# can swift functions and closures conform to Hashable?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, function, closures

Suppose I want to have a `Set` of functions or closures. Here's how I would go about it:

```
typealias HandlerX = () -> ()
static var handlersX = Set<HandlerX>()
```

This produces the following compiler error:

> Type 'HandlerX' (aka '() -> ()') does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

Is this a dead end?

Comment: May a Array of functions solve your problem? if it is, you can have an Array of it like this => var funcArray = Array< () -> Any> = [func1, func2]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is a dead end. Hashable isn't really your problem; there's no way to decide whether two closures are Equal (which is a base requirement of Hashable).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper struct for closure

```
struct Hashed<T>: Hashable {

  let value: T
  let hash: Int

  init(value: T, hash: Int) {
    self.value = value
    self.hash = hash
  }

  public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(hash)
  }

  static func == (lhs: Hashed<T>, rhs: Hashed<T>) -> Bool {
      lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
  }
}
```

But you need to understand the identity of your closures. For example, it can be the class that created it, or `#filename + #line`, or always unique with `UUID()`