# In Swift, How can I declare a Dictionary where the key is a function? (does not conform to protocol 'Hashable')

Tags: swift, function, dictionary, pointers, key

I am trying to achieve this in Swift:

```
let dict : [ () -> () : String]
//error: type '() -> ()' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'
//let dict : [ () -> () : String]
//^
```

But getting the error '() -> ()' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'. How can I fix that error?

Edit: 
I am porting a Finite State Machine from Lua where the key happens to be a function. (I know that may be weird in any other language but for Lua is ok).
The Lua code:

```
local machine = {}

machine [Entry] = {loop = Entry, go = Another, gosub = sub } 
machine [Another] = {go = Entry, loop = Another, next = Next } 
machine [Next] = {startAgain = Entry } 
machine [sub] = {out = Entry, next = Next, gosub = indoor, goOutDoor = outdoor } 
machine [indoor] = {out = sub, next = sub } 
machine [outdoor] = {next = sub }
```

Comment: can you explain more about what you're trying to do with the dictionary? there is probably a better way to implement it without having to use functions for keys.

Comment: There's certainly a better way to code this in Swift. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Related: [can swift functions and closures conform to Hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35161853/2415822)

Comment: Your Lua code is not a good example to show what you want to achieve. The values are not string, the keys are not specified. Please show what are `Entry`, `Another`, `Next`, `sub`... and the usage example of `machine`.

Comment: As I wrote "the key happens to be a function". Entry, Another, Next, sub are functions. I just need a dictionary where the keys are functions.

Comment: As already explained in comments and an answer, you cannot use function type in Swift `Dictionary`. If **_NO, You cannot do this_** is what you want, just _accept_ the answer of Duncan C and ignore my comments. If you want some alternative or workaround, show enough info as I wrote before.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you **can** fix it. The key for a dictionary must conform to the `Hashable` protocol. That means that it has an Int hashValue property, and that it implements the `==` operator. (See this link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable)

Functions don't conform to the `Hashable` protocol, so they can't be dictionary keys.