# Swift - Type '' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

Tags: swift

So I have this struct:

```swift
struct ListAction: Hashable {
    let label: String
    let action: (() -> Void)? = nil
    let command: Command? = nil
}
```

But I get an error on the line it's declared on saying `Type 'ListAction' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'`.

I can get rid of the error if I remove the line defining the `action` constant but I don't want to remove that line permanently.

I'm using Swift 5.1.

Comment: It might be because your action is not of type Hashable. Please refer to this link for more information. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable

Comment: @Bikram Yeah it looks like that's the issue. How would I go about making that Hashable though?

Comment: You might check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161853/can-swift-functions-and-closures-conform-to-hashable

Comment: @LukeChambers There's an example for that in the above link

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Supply your own implementation for `Hashable` by overriding `hash(into:)` and call `combine` on all the relevant properties.

```
struct ListAction: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: ListAction, rhs: ListAction) -> Bool {
        return lhs.label == rhs.label && lhs.command == rhs.command
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(label)
        hasher.combine(command)
    }

    let label: String
    let action: (() -> Void)? = nil
    let command: Command? = nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The struct needs a unique identifier to conform to Hashable. You can simply add a UID to your struct and then add a hash function as a comparison function to make the comparison.

```
struct ListAction: Codable, Hashable {
    var uid = UUID().uuidString
    let label: String
    let action: (() -> Void)? = nil
    let command: Command? = nil
    
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.uid == rhs.uid
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(uid)
    }
    
}
```

you can add that those two functions and and var uid to any struct you have problems making Hashable.

It's a good practice to add extensions to your structs that require protocol functions like hash.

```
struct ListAction {
var uid = UUID().uuidString // add this 
    let label: String
    let action: (() -> Void)? = nil
    let command: Command? = nil
}    
// add this to make your struct conform to Hashable
extension ListAction: Hashable {
        static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
            lhs.uid == rhs.uid
        }
        func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
            hasher.combine(uid)
        }
    }
```